# How to create better looking tables in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi i add a lot of tables to wordpress one option is to add tables as you copy them from excel and simply post them. They look ugly like in this post here on my site [candytech](http://candytech.in/moto-e-gen-2-may-have-4g-lte-and-android-lollipop/)

I tried afew plugins it makes site slow, Please anyone guide how to create a table without a plugin which look good like an excel table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TablePress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/) to embed tables into your posts and pages.

To speed up your WordPress site (load-times), you can use [WP Performance Score Booster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-performance-score-booster/).

That's all I always do. I hope this helps.

If you don't want to use any plugin, then you have to create tables using HTML manually and paste it (HTML code).